# How can I Efficiently Check if the Running User has a Standard Permission?

Tags: permissions, permission-sets

There is a method `FeatureManagement.checkPermission` to check efficiently if a user has a custom permission.

How can we check efficiently  if a user has a standard permission instead?

For example, when I try to find if a user has `Manage Profiles and Permission Sets` permission and when I run the following code under system administrator user

```
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ v: ' + FeatureManagement.checkPermission('ManageProfilesPermissionsets')  );
```

I receive

```
@@@ v: false
```

results despite system administrator has `Manage Profiles and Permission Sets` permission.

Answer (score 0):

So the shortest code is the following:

```
![SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet where PermissionsManageProfilesPermissionsets = true AND Id IN (select PermissionSetId from PermissionSetAssignment where AssigneeId =:UserInfo.getUserId())].isEmpty();
```

However, if there is a need to check for two or more different standard permission, it is not efficient to perform multiple SOQL query and in such case it is still needed to loop through the query results like following:

```
Boolean result = false;
Boolean manageProfiles = false;
Boolean customizeApp = false;
for (PermissionSet ps: [SELECT PermissionsManageProfilesPermissionsets, PermissionsCustomizeApplication FROM PermissionSet where ID IN (select PermissionSetId from PermissionSetAssignment where AssigneeId =:UserInfo.getUserId())]) {
    if (ps.PermissionsManageProfilesPermissionsets) manageProfiles = true;
    if (ps.PermissionsCustomizeApplication ) customizeApp = true;
    if (manageProfiles && customizeApp) break;
}
result = manageProfiles && customizeApp;
System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, '@@@ v: ' + result );
```

which yields

```
@@@ v: true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<PermissionSet> userPermissionsList = [SELECT PermissionsManageProfilesPermissionsets, PermissionsCustomizeApplication 
    FROM PermissionSet 
    WHERE(PermissionsManageProfilesPermissionsets = true OR PermissionsCustomizeApplication = true) 
    AND Id IN (select PermissionSetId from PermissionSetAssignment where AssigneeId =:UserInfo.getUserId())];
    String userPermissions= String.join(userPermissionsList , '-');
    Boolean userHasPermission = (userPermissions.contains('PermissionsManageProfilesPermissionsets:true') 
&& userPermissions.contains('PermissionsCustomizeApplication:true'));
    System.debug(userHasPermission); //true
```

would be shorter way to write it.

Comment: in my actual case I need to check two permissions, namely ManageProfilesPermissions and CustomizeApplication, and these two permissions might be assigned by two permission sets so I will still have to query both and loop through the results

Comment: Well, it is possible without for but not necessarily better option. I updated my answer.

Comment: The idea of concatenating SObject records and then checking if the concatenated string contains required permission is interesting. However, I find `? true : false;` to be extra in your code snippet.

Comment: Yup, it is extra. Thanks for pointing it out. Concatenating & using contains is not something I did before but for me it was only way to remove for loop.